# flask wtforms_alchemy object has no attribute

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login, flask-restful

I just started doing flask restful api and trying to register a user by sending a POST request to `localhost:5000/api/v1/users`. The required fields are email and password. Here's the curl request to create a user `curl http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users -d "email=admin@example.com&password=password" -X POST -v`

But it returns me this error: `AttributeError: 'UserCreateForm' object has no attribute 'password'`

Below is some snip of my code

views.py

```
class UserView(restful.Resource):
    def post(self):
        form = UserCreateForm()
        if not form.validate_on_submit():
            return form.errors, 422

        user = User(email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return UserSerializer(user).data
```

forms.py

```
BaseModelForm = model_form_factory(Form)

class ModelForm(BaseModelForm):
    @classmethod
    def get_session(self):
        return db.session

class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

models.py ( I tired to place the `UserMixin` to second, still getting same error )

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

Also, I have `login_manager.user_loader` included, so I don't think it will be issue with flask login.

And is there a documentation for wtform_alchemy? I totaly don't get how it works to create the form automatically from the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserCreateForm` will inherit its fields from the columns you define on `User`. `User` has no column named `password`, therefore `UserCreateForm` doesn't have such a field. You'll have to add the field yourself.

```
from wtforms.fields import PasswordField

class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    password = PasswordField()
```

The [WTForms-Alchemy docs](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/column_conversion.html#adding-overriding-fields) talk about adding and overriding fields.

Comment: What if I want different name, e.g `fname` in the database column, and I want to add fields `firstname` to the form. If I do `firstname = TextField()` would the value from this field passed to the `fname` column in my database?

Comment: Not without you telling it to. WTForms-Alchemy can only make connections when the names match. If you need to do any custom mapping, you need to include that yourself. Ideally you wouldn't give it one name in the model and another name in the form. But in the case of password, you could implement your own `populate_obj` and include `obj.password = self.password.data` or something along those lines.

Comment: The password works now, but I'm curious how. You had `password` in the form field, but in the db column it's `password_hash` and there's no mapping as you mentioned.

Comment: It works because `User` has an attribute (but not a `Column`) named `password`. If it didn't, you'd need to add something to assign a value to `password_hash`.

Comment: What do I need to add in that case?

Comment: It's hard to answer questions in comments. If your original question has been solved, please consider accepting this answer and asking a new question to allow for proper answers.